# facing issue with moment.js:

Tags: javascript, angularjs, momentjs

when i post , time starting from 5s,4s,3s,2s,1s, then it's displaying 2s,3s,4s,5s,6s.........
it should start from 1s,2s,3s.....go on

```
moment.lang('en', {
    relativeTime : {
        future: "in %s",
        past:   "%s",
        s:  "%ds",
        m:  "1m",
        mm: "%dm",
        h:  "1h",
        hh: "%dh",
        d:  "1d",
        dd: "%dd",
        M:  "30d",
        MM: function (number) {
          return number * 30 + 'd';
        },
        y:  "365d",
        yy: function (number) {
          return number * 365 + 'd';
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Your description is not very clear to me. Can you modify your question and add some more code? A running example displaying the issue you are describing would be perfect.

Comment: Am using this <span am-time-ago="post.createdTS"></span>   @Andrea